# Facebook Graph API: Add a reaction to a post or remove a reaction from a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create or delete reactions (LIKE, LOVE, HAHA, WOW, SAD, AGRY) with the `Facebook Graph API v2.8`. But there seems to be no way to do it ([documentation link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/reactions)):

> Creating
>
> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.
>
> Deleting
>
> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

Is there really no way to do it? Does anyone know if it's planned for a new version of the API like v2.9?

Comment: well...the docs tell you, and i doubt that it will possible in future versions. why would you want to do that anyway?

Comment: that´s like asking "is it possible" while at the same time quoting the docs clearly mentioning that "it is not possible"...

Comment: Well, I want to be able to add an reaction to a post in my app. I can do that for likes, but not for reactions.

Comment: Correct. You can not do it for reactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in the API docs, there is no way to POST reactions as of now. If it will be available in future API versions is unclear, only Facebook knows that.